# SQL update table by targeting unique row one int less

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

What I have is a table with the following columns

All columns are nvarchar expect for the Date columns which are datetime

`CreateDateA InvIDA StorageIDA CreateDateB  InvIDB StorageIDB UniID`

What I want to do is move the values on each row (based on `UniID`) into the represenative B columns where `UniID` is 1 less, so the 'A' columns where UniID = 2 should go to the B Columns where the UniID = 1.

This is the query i'm using but it's not updating any columns.

```
update InvSubmission
set CreateDateB = CreateDateA,
InvIDB = InvIDA ,
StorageIDB = StorageIDA 
where StorageIDB = StorageIDA and UniID = (select UniID-1 from InvSubmission)
```

There is multiple storageid's in this table, however, each record has a match to at least one other row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PinnyM's answer is close, but in SQL Server, you have to name the updated table in the from clause also:

```
update toUpdate
set CreateDateB = sourceTable.CreateDateA,
    InvIDB = sourceTable.InvIDA
FROM
    InvSubmission toUpdate
        inner Join
    InvSubmission sourceTable
       ON sourceTable.UniID = toUpdate.UniID + 1
       AND sourceTable.StorageIDA = toUpdate.StorageIDB
```

Otherwise, [this note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) becomes relevant:

> If the object being updated is the same as the object in the FROM clause and there is only one reference to the object in the FROM clause, an object alias may or may not be specified

And then you're suffering the same problem that @Yuck pointed out - you're trying to compare the `UniID` value within a single row to a value one less than itself.

Comment: this worked, thank you,  ON sourceTable.UniID = InvSubmission.UniID + 1
 has to be changed to ON sourceTable.UniID = toUpdate.UniID + 1

Answer (score 1):

`UniID = (select UniID-1 from InvSubmission)` is equivalent to `UniID = UniID - 1`. So, for example, you're basically saying:

```
WHERE 2 = (2 - 1)
```

And that's never going to be true, which is why the query isn't modifying anything.

If both the `A` and `B` columns are in the same row you don't even need to qualify by using the `ID` clause. Otherwise you need to self-join like this:

```
update InvSubmission
set CreateDateB = B.CreateDateA,
    InvIDB = B.InvIDA ,
    StorageIDB = B.StorageIDA
from InvSubmission A INNER JOIN
     InvSubmission B ON A.UniID = B.UniId - 1
where A.StorageIDB = A.StorageIDA;
```

As I mentioned it's a little confusing because your example makes it *look* like the columns are all contained in the same row...

Comment: all the columns are on the same row

Answer (score 1):

It may actually depend on which RDBMS you are using (some are finicky on how aliases can be used), but you can try:

```
update InvSubmission
set CreateDateB = sourceTable.CreateDateA,
InvIDB = sourceTable.InvIDA ,
StorageIDB = sourceTable.StorageIDA 
FROM InvSubmission sourceTable
WHERE sourceTable.UniID = InvSubmission.UniID + 1
```

Comment: This is in essence the same as what the OP had, except you changed the `- 1` to `+ 1`. See my answer for why this won't work.

Comment: The OP query had a condition 'StorageIDB = StorageIDA' which is likely the cause of 0 rows updated. Also, the OP query was attempting to update the A fields to the B fields on the same row of data.  The subquery with 'UniID - 1' was meaningless, but not quite for the reason you described.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer is correct for SQL Server.  Postgres and some others won't have a problem with this query.  Hence the disclaimer about the RDBMS.